# How to use Twitter Bootstrap in Polymer element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer

Is there any way to use Bootstrap in Polymer element. bootstrap.css works but bootstrap.js does not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap.js has some problems with shadow DOM (basically, it can't see them, and so can't manipulate them). This discussion gives some further details:

https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/web-ui/z_cdW-s-4Xw/NYdS9GSpXC4J